Max Field from Grouped Table
I have a grouped table that looks like this:



End_of_Month_Date
VersionId




2024-06-30
1


2024-06-30
2


2024-07-31
1


2024-07-31
2


2024-07-31
3


2024-07-31
5



For each month end, I want to pull in the Max Version Id so that in the end I have unique End of month dates and max(VersionId)'s.  I've tried writing the code but it's not working correctly.
select distinct c.END_OF_MONTH_DATE, c.VERSION_ID, 'Assets'
    from dbo.Contracts_Version_Details c
        inner join(
            select distinct max(c1.Version_Id) as MaxVersionId, c1.END_OF_MONTH_DATE
            from dbo.Contracts_Version_Details c1
            group by c1.End_of_month_date) mv
            on c.VERSION_ID = mv.MaxVersionId
        inner join(
                    select distinct max(c2.END_OF_MONTH_DATE) as MaxDate, c2.VERSION_ID
                    from dbo.Contracts_Version_Details c2
                    group by c2.VERSION_ID
                ) as md
                on c.END_OF_MONTH_DATE = md.MaxDate


Please consider following these suggestions.


For each month end ... unique End of month dates and (max)version id's.

How about this?
select 
  End_of_Month_Date
, max( VersionId ) 
from Contracts_Version_Details 
group by End_of_Month_Date
order by End_of_Month_Date 
; 


Thank you, this works perfect.  I feel a little silly that I was so far off with the lengthy code that i was attempting to use.


For each month end, I want to pull in the Max Version Id

MAX(VersionId) OVER (PARTITION BY End_of_Month_Date) is enough.

This might get you closer:
SELECT DISTINCT c.END_OF_MONTH_DATE, c.VERSION_ID, mv.max_version_id, meom.max_EOM, 'Assets'
from dbo.Contracts_Version_Details c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT END_OF_MONTH_DATE, max(x.version_id) as max_version_id
    FROM dbo.Contracts_Version_Details as x
    GROUP BY END_OF_MONTH_DATE
) as mv
    ON c.END_OF_MONTH_DATE = mv.END_OF_MONTH_DATE
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT x.version_id, max(x.END_OF_MONTH_DATE) as max_EOM
    FROM dbo.Contracts_Version_Details as x
    GROUP BY version_id
) as meom
    ON c.version_id = meom.version_id



